# DataGrid in .NET MAUI

Tags: datagrid, maui

I am working on a .NET MAUI project to create a desktop application and I need to create a DataGrid. I read the documentation but I could not find "DataGrid" there. I only found "Grid" which is used to divide the form in rows and columns.

In Winforms we have a [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8) class. Is there any "DataGrid" or anything like this "DataGrid" in .NET MAUI?

Comment: TableView, ListView or CollectionView. Also, third party options are available. (Free and paid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` control hasn't been available or approachable in **.NET MAUI**. However, you can follow up this feature request: [[Enhancement] DataGrid Control](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1259) on Github.

As an alternative solution, you can use this package [Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid). For more details, you can refer to [Getting Started with .NET MAUI DataGrid](https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/datagrid/getting-started) on how to use it.

Comment: thas a really expensive alternative solution. its a shame to not have a datagrid in the default controls set.

Answer (score 0):

I came across DevExpress which offers free licensing for their DataGrid control .NET MAUI version.

I have not used the .NET Maui version of their DataGrid and therefore cannot comment on it.

I am not affiliate with them.

https://www.devexpress.com/maui/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).