# .NET MAUI: Scrollable list of log data

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0

I'm making an application for gathering serial communication data and presenting it in a log window.  This is my first .NET MAUI application, and I'm having problems with finding a way that performs well.

Preferably I would like to have columns with timestamp, raw hex bytes and ascii strings.  But using a ListView with a Grid for each line with perhaps a couple hundred lines is not performing very well even on my Macbook M1 Max.  It's really sluggish and completely unusable.

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ReceivedDataBuffer}"
    ios:ListView.RowAnimationsEnabled="False"
    HasUnevenRows="False"
    CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ReceivedData">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0"
                            Text="{Binding Timestamp}"
                            FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                            Text="{Binding HexString}"
                            FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Is there a way to get the ListView to perform better?  Or is there a control that's better suited to show a lot of logged data (approx. 10,000 lines) with multiple properties?

Comment: Is this ListView your only element? No parent?

Comment: Also, always test performance in Release. Debug is expected to be slow.

Comment: Will someone be scrolling through 10,000 lines of logging data? Maybe a rolling list would be better where you show 100 lines, but keep the rest of the data in a log file.

Comment: No, the ListView won't be the only element.  I will eventually add a menu bar to set serial port, baudrate, add various control buttons etc.

Could be that scrolling back 10,000 lines is cumbersome.  Only way will be using a scrollbar of course.  But in worst case I need to set a lower limit.  In any case, I still had problems just with around 100 lines.

Comment: Try using a CollectionView, You will see some improvement for updating it.

Comment: CollectionView has built in incremental loading, or for that much data I would probably build in paging

Comment: https://www.sharpnado.com/xamarin-forms-maui-collectionview-performance-the-10-golden-rule/

Comment: Re @H.A.H.'s comment about testing in Release: *most* of the performance gain from Release can be seen simply by stopping the debugger, and relaunching the app from simulator's home page. (Or use "Start without Debugging" menu item.) Having an attached debugger disables JIT-compilation; once the debugger is removed, most Debug code will perform nearly as well as the Release version. Even better, do this on an actual device.

Comment: Well, CollectionView seems to be working fine.  But I don't have any control of the scrolling. When the number of items in the ObservableCollection exceeds the capacity of the CollectionView, I have to manually scroll to see new items. No matter if I add them at the beginning or the end.  ScrollTo() doesn't work (intellisense states "To be added" on all relevant properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DataGrid` instead of `ListView` if you want to perform well. As the `DataGrid` can show different data types in different types of columns and it will only load what you scroll to.

I use the code below to show **10,000** lines of pseudo data in `DataGrid` and it performs well.

```
for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++)
{
      orderInfo.Add(new OrderInfo("testdata column"+i, "testdata column" + i, "testdata column" + i, "testdata column" + i, "testdata column" + i));
}
```

And you can refer to [DataGrid in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74555929/datagrid-in-net-maui/74556776#74556776) on how to use it.

Comment: I haven't heard from you for a few days. May I confirm if there is anything else that I can help?